# If you have the cofactors of a matrix, how can you find that matrix from its cofactors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have all the cofactors of a matrix (lets say A) how can you find that matrix (A)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Denote cofactor matrix $C=\mathrm{cof}(A)$. According to the relation
$$C^T=\det(A)A^{-1}$$
We know $\det C^T=\det\Big(\det(A)A^{-1}\Big)=(\det A)^n\det A^{-1}=(\det A)^{n-1}$.

So if $\det C\neq0$, we have
$$A=(A^{-1})^{-1}=\Big(\frac{C^T}{\det A}\Big)^{-1}=\pm(\det C)^\frac{1}{1-n}~C^{-T}$$

Thanks to @Robert Israel, note that when $n$ is odd, $(\det A)^{n-1}=(\det -A)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Of course this assumes $C$ (and thus $A$) is invertible.  If $C$ isn't invertible, $A$ is not determined by $C$.

Comment: @ Robert Israel Is there a simple example of two different matrices that have the same cofactor matrix?

Comment: If $n \ge 3$, any $n \times n$ matrix with rank $\le 1$ has all its cofactors $0$.

Comment: Another problem: if $n$ is odd, $-A$ and $A$ have the same cofactors.  So $A$ is at most determined up to a factor of $-1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh, that's right. Thanks.